# How to properly parse this JSON response with Volley in Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-volley

I'm having hard times trying to parse the following JSON and save it in a list.

```
{
  "statut": "Success",
  "rubrique": [
    {
      "rubrique": "Accueil",
      "position": "1"
    },
    {
      "rubrique": "Films",
      "position": "2"
    },
    {
      "rubrique": "Séries",
      "position": "3"
    },
    {
      "rubrique": "Sketchs",
      "position": "4"
    },
    {
      "rubrique": "Musique",
      "position": "5"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried several methods then the below code worked,exept my list only contains one item: Musique

```
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity)
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, endpoint,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                val stringResponse = response.toString()
                val jsonObj = JSONObject(stringResponse)
                val jsonArray: JSONArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("rubrique")

                for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                    val innerBlock: JSONObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                    val item: RubriqueItem = RubriqueItem()
                    item.position = innerBlock.getString("position")
                    item.rubrique = innerBlock.getString("rubrique")

                    categories?.add(item)
                }
                binding?.viewPagerMain?.adapter = BaseCategoriesFragmentPagerAdapter(
                    parentFragmentManager, categories)
                binding?.tabLayout?.setupWithViewPager(binding?.viewPagerMain)
            },
            Response.ErrorListener {error -> error.printStackTrace() })
        queue.add(stringRequest)
```

categories is ArrayList which I need to pass to the ViewPager's adapter. Tried to figure out a way to pass the index but I'm new to Kotlin can't figure out yet

Any hint is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) lib for that.

First prepare the data class for the response.

ApiResponse.kt:

```
data class Rubrique(
    val rubrique: String,
    val position: String
)

data class ApiResponse(
    val statut: String,
    val rubrique: List<Rubrique>
)
```

And then to parse the response you just need one line:

```
val responseObject = Gson().fromJson(stringResponse, ApiResponse::class.java)
```

`responseObject` will have all the info. And the list in `responseObject.rubrique`.

Your code would be after this:

```
val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, endpoint,
    Response.Listener<String> { response ->
        val responseObject = Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), ApiResponse::class.java)
        binding?.viewPagerMain?.adapter = BaseCategoriesFragmentPagerAdapter(
            parentFragmentManager, responseObject.rubrique)
        binding?.tabLayout?.setupWithViewPager(binding?.viewPagerMain)
    },
    Response.ErrorListener {error -> error.printStackTrace() })
queue.add(stringRequest)
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution,but what is json in  private var categories: ArrayList<RubriqueItem>? = ArrayList() ?

Comment: After this line you have all the list in `responseObject.rubrique` as `List<Rubrique>` and each element will have the `rubrique` and `position` attributes

Comment: Thanks, will definitely use this method. Thank you

Comment: I think kotlinx.serialization is way better for this purpose as it does not use reflection and hence alot faster. I'd recommended that over Gson for less boilerplate and higher performance @Lyra

Comment: Would you mind to provide an example that I can follow?

Comment: I've updated the sample. I don't use the kotlinx.serialization yet because I'm waiting until it leaves the experimental phase. They are quite similar in performance and syntax so changing from one to the other should be easy.

Comment: @jeprubio Well, I tried the last snipet: responseObject.rubrique is arising a type mismatch, it's a ```(Mutable) List<RurbiqueItem>!``` while ```ArrayList<RubriqueItem>``` is expected. So I tried to cast ```responseObject.rubrique``` to ```ArrayList<RebriqueItem>?```

Comment: Well, yes and no, best practices is to program to interfaces and not specific implementations, it's one of the basics of object oriented programming so you should accept in the adapter List as a parameter instead of ListArray, but I'm just saying, feel free to follow this practice or not

Answer (score 1):

Where exactly did you initialize "categories"?

I see 2 possible problems here:
1 -> categories only contains your last data. (you could see if it is that adding:

```
Log.d("VolleyRequestResult", categories.toString()
```

just before

```
binding?.viewPagerMain?.adapter = BaseCategoriesFragmentPagerAdapter(
                    parentFragmentManager, categories)
```

2 -> your BaseCategoriesFragmentPagerAdapter only display the last data (you should share this code so we can better understand what is happening)

Comment: like this:  private var categories: ArrayList<RubriqueItem>? = ArrayList(). The adapter is fine, its simply assign each item to tabs and get item count from categories size